# On mac OS, I've enabled PHP but seem to have permission problems. How do I enable subdirectories?

Tags: php, macos, webserver

Whenever I install a library that requires using subdirectories, it seems like I have to go to chmod hell. How can I make it where all subdirectories are accessible by PHP?

C:\Library\Webserver\Documents is the current root of my webserver.

Comment: Just a note... OS X does not use the concept of lettered drives like Windows does so C:\Library\Webserver\Documents = /Library/Webserver/Documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **-R** switch when doing chmod, and it will set the permissions on all the subdirectories as well.

```
chmod -R somedirectory/
```

Answer (score 1):

Often times the Apache process runs under the user "nobody". Try

```
chown nobody /Library/Webserver/Documents
```

Also, if you run chmod recursively it will affect child directories

```
chmod -R /some folder/
```